# Zend Studio error - Generating Getters and Setters failed

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio

I've just installed new Zend Studio 9.0.0 on Windows XP.

An error window with message:

> "Generating Getters and Setters failed"

appears every time I'm trying to generate getters and setters. Code generating in Zend Studio 7 on the same PC works well. I didn't change anything in PHP code Templates or anywhere else.

I also had this problem on another computer on Zend Studio 8 a few monthes ago but didn't find any solution.

http://clip2net.com/s/1C5OO

Comment: open a ticket with Zend Support

Answer (score 0):

Double check your list of properties/members for syntax/typos. I had a long list and on one line after the semi-colon, I had an erroneus comma. Once I removed the comma, the Getter/Setter operation succeeded.

Comment: I can see that this was your first answer to a question, so you didn't have the rep to post this as a comment, but in the future, you might want to consider posting this as a comment. Answers are supposed to be a solution to the problem that you are pretty confident will solve the problem.